# Gradle Exclude Rules

Tags: android, maven, gradle

i try to automate uploading to some internal maven repo. I'm using Gradle 2.14.1 in one of my Android Librarys.

The problem i'm facing is that when i upload the library the pom created does not contain any exclude rules. I read about the pom.withXMl closure and i may have to extend this a bit, but im struggle how to do that.

```
compile('com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:1.9.0') {
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}
```

For some debugging purpose i used :

```
publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId packageName
            version = libraryVersion
            artifactId project.getName()
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-${ending}.aar")
            configurations.getByName("_releaseCompile").allDependencies.each {

                if (it.getGroup().equals("com.squareup.retrofit")) {
                    it.properties.each { prop ->

                        if (prop.key.equals("excludeRules")) {
                            println("--> value ->" + prop.getValue());

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

That outputs:

--> value ->[org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultExcludeRule@6c0cb00, org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultExcludeRule@553bcdcd, org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultExcludeRule@707d760]

Is there a smart way to access those Rules ? Maybe those values are stored somewhere else also ?

The packagename "org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultExcludeRule" already tells me that this in internal API. Im kinda stuck here at the moment as i want to write the task more generic so that it can be reused more easy.

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Honestly, just upgrade to `retrofit2`, you can see the POM file(https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-converters/simplexml/pom.xml) does not contain `stax` or `xpp3`.

Comment: That dependency is used in an project that is used in a lot of apps, so theres no easy change here as i cant touch those project at the moment. I agree that i have to change it, but others need to work with this before i can remove this dependency

Comment: I do not think that there is a way. Just reuse those exclude rules in the application on the same dependency.

Comment: Well, at the moment around 40 internal apps using that, i dont want to touch them at the moment as there will be more and i need a more general solution as it may come that i run in this "exclude" case again.